# mocking UrlEncoder in a static method

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I'm having trouble mocking UrlEncode.encode method which is inside a static method.

MyEncodeClass.java has this method

```
public static myEncode(String s) {
  UrlEncoder.encode(s, "utf-8");
}
```

I want to force throw an exception when UrlEncode.encode method is called.

```
@Test(expect = UnsupportedEncodingException.class)
public void myTest() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(URLEncoder.class);        
    when(URLEncoder.encode("aa", "utf-8")).thenThrow(UnsupportedEncodingException.class);    
    MyEncodeClass.myEncode("aa");
}
```

but I always get the following exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.mock.MockCreationSettings.isUsingConstructor()Z
```

Comment: While I respect your dedication to code coverage in your tests, you're seriously trying to mock an UnsupportedEncodingException in the event that A) A dev typos or B) UTF-8 is no longer supported? Wouldn't it just be easier to log a fatal error and System exit? (Sorry, I can't actually help you with your problem, as I don't do much more complex than EasyMock. Good luck though)

Comment: yes I know this is a very twisted case. If too much I might just skip it with an explanation why.

Comment: Nah, it's all good, do what you want to do, but I had to take the opportunity to kid around with you. Good luck with your issue.

Comment: What's the relationship between `UrlEncode` and `URLEncoder`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

it is because of the version conflict between PowerMockito and Mockito artifacts. "MockCreationSettings.isUsingConstructor" method is removed in new versions, so you need to be sure you are using correct versions. e.g use PowerMockito version 1.6.2 with Mockito version 1.10.19 (this version has that missing method)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately didn't helped my case. PowerMockito & Mockito got some magic dependencies between them. The official supported versions tips didn't solve the issue either https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockitousage#supported-versions